# Javascript click on specific element always uses wrong/other element id

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I have several html pages and each one has a varying number of buttons that appear based on the page's content.

In just Javascript (since I don't use jquery), I am trying to have the same few lines of code apply to the respective button that was clicked, with the exception that the id tag has to be 'concatenated' into a variable based on the respective button that was clicked.

I saw other solutions on here that cycled through the elements of the class (in this case the "zoom_buttonClass"). However, when I attempt this, regardless of number of buttons on the page or which button was clicked, it is always the LAST button in the list that seems to be the one seen as clicked.

I need to always check if buttons are clicked, but how do I apply the actions based on the ACTUAL button that was clicked?

My HTML and JS code snippets are below:

Thanks in advance.

HTML code:

```
<div class="modalClass" id="myModalID">
    <span class="closeModalClass" aria-label="Close Photo Enlargement Modal Box">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal_contentClass" id="modalEnlargementID">
</div>
<div id="captionID"></div>
```

JS code:

```
for (var i = 0;i < document.getElementsByClassName("zoom_buttonClass").length;i++){
document.getElementsByClassName("zoom_buttonClass")[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction
  (var attribute = this.getAttribute("id");
    var photoIDstring = "photo"+counterX+"ID";
    document.getElementById('myModalID').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('captionID').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("modalEnlargementID").src = document.getElementById(photoIDstring).src;
    captionText.innerText = document.getElementById(photoIDstring).alt;
  ), false);
};
```

Comment: Your code is invalid so I'm not sure there's much we can figure out from it.

Comment: Thank Niet.  You're right.  Something got garbled in the code because I'm flailing at this and trying every which way to get it working.  But the concept of the question still stands.  I'll try and get the 'correct' code back and post that snippet such as it is.

Comment: Does `counterX` ever change? It seems like you are selecting the same ID every time. Are you meaning to use `attribute` there instead?

Comment: Hi mhodges.  My apologies.  That "var attribute" is actually leftover code from a previous attempt I made at this.  I don't actually use it anywhere.  photoIDstring is indeed supposed to have a different 'counterX' for each button, so the string would be something like "photo1ID", "photo2ID", "photo3ID"... "photo5ID", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I started again and I think I may have hit upon a solution.  It seems to work.

```
var captionText = document.getElementById("captionID");
var howManyButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("zoom_buttonClass").length;
var buttonCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("zoom_buttonClass");
for (let i=0; i < howManyButtons; i++) {
  buttonCollection[i].onclick = function() {
  let photoIDstring = "photo"+(i+1)+"ID";
  document.getElementById('myModalID').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('captionID').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("modalEnlargementID").src = document.getElementById(photoIDstring).src;
  captionText.innerText = document.getElementById(photoIDstring).alt;
  }
}
```